# Add a solid white border at top and left to get 3d effect

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to mimic the effect as shown here:

[image: Login]

The border at the top and left of the box is giving it a nice embossed effect. I tried the same with the following:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="nl-login">
</div>

<!-- CSS -->
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body{
    background-color:#3E4C79;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#nl-login{
    width:400px;
    height:250px;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    margin:40px auto;   
    opacity:0.3;
    box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px #fff;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
```

But it's not even close to it. I think it has got to do with having a better pair of border and box-shadow values which I can't seem to zero in on. Any help?

Here is a [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3mjeLo00/) just in case.

Comment: You know about `inset`, `border` and `ridge` border styles, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `opacity: 0.3;` here which affects the entire element as well as its children. The correct approach would be to use an `rgba()` background color, along with `rgba()` for the border color. Also removing the right and bottom borders produces the desired result (at least a close approximation)

```
#nl-login{
    width:400px;
    height:250px;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    margin:40px auto;   
    /*box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px #fff;*/
    border:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/3mjeLo00/1/

Comment: Nice explanation. Upvoted. Unfortunately, I can only accept 1 answer. It's gonna be a tough decision.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use two comma separated `box-shadow`s:

```
box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
```

As in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanchaer/dte4mxjj/2/).

It makes sense to me to use shadows as we are creating light effects. Plus this technique allows blur / spread, and leaves the border and outline attributes available if you want to use them for other effects.

Comment: Upvoted. Unfortunately, I can only accept 1 answer. It's gonna be a tough decision.

Answer (score 1):

Do not make the whole element semi-transparent (*as that will affect all descendant elements*). Use alpha on the background color.

And you can also make the borders semi transparent (*without using any shadow*).

```
#nl-login{
    width:400px;
    height:250px;
    background-color:rgba(240,240,240,0.3);
    margin:40px auto;
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:rgba(240,240,240,0.5) /*top border*/
               rgba(0,0,0,0.5)  /*right border*/
               rgba(0,0,0,0.5) /*bottom border*/
               rgba(240,240,240,0.5) /*left border*/;
}
```

---

Full example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #3E4C79;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#nl-login {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.3);
  margin: 40px auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.5) 
                rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 
                rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 
                rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="nl-login">
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted. Unfortunately, I can only accept 1 answer. It's gonna be a tough decision.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `box-shadow` and remove the `border` and `opacity` and add `background` as `rgba()`

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
html{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
body{
 background-color:#3E4C79;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
#nl-login{
 width:400px;
 height:250px;
 background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) inset;
 margin:40px auto; 
}
```

```html
<div id="nl-login">
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted. Unfortunately, I can only accept 1 answer. It's gonna be a tough decision.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with just borders, just use `rgba` with lover opacity for left and bottom border.

```css
body {
  background-color: #3E4C79;
  margin: 0;
}
#nl-login {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #737D9C;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(62, 76, 121, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="nl-login"></div>
```

Comment: Upvoted. Unfortunately, I can only accept 1 answer. It's gonna be a tough decision.